# How to store multiple files (two list and a df) by pickle in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pickle

I'm new using python programming. I have developed a program, and i have created 2 list (a and b) and also a dataframe using pandas. 
I wanted to save all them together by using pickle, so that, then i can load them in another script that i want to create. 
I have read different tutorials but i dont manage to do it... The variables are like this:

```
a=['red','yellow',blue']

b=[[A1,F2,G8],[V,N],[I]]
```

**df: containing 40 columns and 32 rows**

How can I save them and load in again?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you just plug them into a tuple and then pickle the tuple ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put them together.

Either a tuple, or a dictionary would do.

You can also write a small class to store everything and write that in the file.